# Expect ignoring pattern matching and not exiting

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, expect

I'm new using expect and is puzzling me big time. It works perfectly with one pattern but when the second case comes up it just ignores the exit completely. First, this is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

#Usage migration_test.xpct <ssh_password> <vmname> <no_migraciones>

set timest [ timestamp -format %Y-%m-%d_%H-%M ]
set vmname [lindex $argv 1]

log_file migtest_${vmname}_${timest}.log ;

set password [lindex $argv 0]
set num [lindex $argv 2]
set failureMsg "Status: Failure\n\r"
set timeout 60

spawn ssh admin@localhost -p 10000

expect "yes/no" {
    send "yes\r"
    expect "*?assword" { send "$password\r" }
    } "*?assword" { send "$password\r" }

for {set i 0} {$i < $num} {incr i 1} {
    expect "OVM> " {
        send "show Vm name=$vmname\r"
        expect {
            $failureMsg { }
            -re "Status = Running\n\r" {
                exp_continue
            }
            -re "Server = .*? \\\[(.*?)(1|2)?\\\]\n\r" {
                set destserver $expect_out(2,string);
                if { $destserver == 1 } {
                    send_user "\n\nMIGRATION [ expr $i+1 ] of $num\n\n"
                    send "migrate Vm name=$vmname destServer=serv_prod02\r"
                    expect {
                        -re "JobId: (.*?)\n\r" {
                            set jobid $expect_out(1,string);
                            send "show Job id=$jobid\r";
                            expect {
                                -re "Command:(.*?)\n\r" { send_user "\n\nWaiting 30secs before next migration\n\n";
                                sleep 30; }
                            }
                        }
                        -re "Status: Failure\n\r" { send_user "\n\nExiting\n"; exit 1 }
                    }
                } else {
                    send_user "\n\nMIGRATION [expr $i+1] of $num\n\n"
                    send "migrate Vm name=$vmname destServer=serv_prod01\r"
                    expect {
                        -re "JobId: (.*?)\n\r" {
                            set jobid $expect_out(1,string);
                            send "show Job id=$jobid\r";
                            expect {
                                -re "Command:(.*?)\n\r" { send_user "\n\nWaiting 30secs before next migration\n\n";
                                sleep 30; }
                            }
                        }
                        -re "Status: Failure\n\r" { send_user "\n\nExiting\n"; exit 1 }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

The problem comes when it reaches the "migrate vm" section. That's a job I'm sending to a CLI (oracle ovm cli to be precise) and the job can either fail or success. I want to print the job details when it success but finish the entire execution if the job fails (since it already shows the reason and I don't have to expand the job details).

Here is how the output of a successful job looks:

> MIGRATION 5 of 12
>
> migrate Vm name=slestest_temp_share_vm destServer=serv_prod01
>   Command: migrate Vm name=slestest_temp_share_vm
>   destServer=serv_prod01
>   Status: Success 
>   Time: 2016-04-13 10:45:24,174
>   JobId: 12345678978
>   OVM> show Job id=12345678978
>   Command: show Job id=12345678978
>   Status: Success Time: 2016-04-13 10:45:24,188
>   Data:
>
> > Run State = Success
> >     Summary State = Success
> >     Done = Yes
> >     Summary Done = Yes
> >     Job Group = No
> >     Username = admin
> >     Creation Time = Apr 13, 2016 10:44:45 am
> >     Start Time = Apr 13, 201 10:44:45 am
> >     End Time = Apr 13, 2016 10:45:23 am
> >     Duration = 37s
> >     Id = 12345678978  [Migrate Vm: slestest_temp_share_vm to Server: serv_prod01]
> >     Name = Migrate Vm: slestest_temp_share_vm to Server:serv_prod01
> >     Description = Migrate Vm: slestest_temp_share_vm to
> >     Server: serv_prod01   Locked = false 
> >     OVM>
>
> Waiting 30secs before next migration

And here is how a failured job looks like:

> MIGRATION 4 of 12
>
> migrate Vm name=slestest_temp_share_vm destServer=serv_prod01
>   Command: migrate Vm name=slestest_temp_share_vm destServer=serv_prod01
>   Status: Failure
>   Time: 2016-04-13 11:31:08,819
>   JobId: 1460564963372
>   Error Msg: Job failed on Core: OVMAPI_5001E Job: 1460564963372/Migrate Vm: slestest_temp_share_vm to Server: serv_prod01/Migrate Vm: slestest_temp_share_vm serv_prod01, failed. Job Failure Event: 1460565064570/Server Async Command Failed/OVMEVT_00C014D_001 Async command failed serv_prod02. Object: slestest_temp_share_vm, PID: 1724,
>   Server error: Command: ['xm', 'migrate', '--live', '0004fb00000600009f354416bab38df6', '8.8.8.1'] failed (1): stderr: Error: ti
>
> > stdout: Usage: xm migrate
>
> Migrate a domain to another machine.
>
> Options:
>
> -h, --help           Print this help.
>   -l, --live           Use live migration.
>   -p=portnum, --port=portnum
>                        Use specified port for migration.
>   -n=nodenum, --node=nodenum
>                       Use specified NUMA node on target.
>   -s, --ssl            Use ssl connection for migration.
>   -c, --change_home_server
>                     Change home server for managed domains.
>
> , on server: serv_prod02, associated with object: 0004fb00000600009f354416bab38df6 [Wed Apr 13 11:31:04 2016]

Why does the `Status: Failure` is ignored? Also, when that happens it seems it jumps an iteration of the loop, if it was in the 5th it then shows "Migration 7 of 12" for example.

Thanks everyone

Comment: tl;dr. Run your script with `expect -d` to turn on verbose debug output, and expect will tell you why it didn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some tests I found the problem. It seems I didn't understand how the timeout worked in expect. Every time a failured migration was performed it exceeded the timeout.

This wasn't evident for me because, although the timeout was exceeded, the script still kept waiting for the answer and printed it anyways, just none of the patterns I was expecting to get were being checked.

The solution was either use the "timeout" command or set it higher. I did the later and everything is running fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two things, one you can rewrite code to avoid duplicacy. Second, I think you are matching for both `\n\r` at the end of pattern. Try with `\n` alone or use `\n?\r?` which will match zero, one, or both line endings.

```
-re "Server = .*? \\\[(.*?)(1|2)?\\\]\n" {
    set destserver $expect_out(2,string);
    send_user "\n\nMIGRATION [ expr $i+1 ] of $num\n\n"
    if { $destserver == 1 } {
        send "migrate Vm name=$vmname destServer=serv_prod02\r"
    } else {
        send "migrate Vm name=$vmname destServer=serv_prod01\r"
    }

    expect {
        -re "JobId: (.*?)\n" {
            set jobid $expect_out(1,string);
            send "show Job id=$jobid\r";
            expect {
               -re "Command:(.*?)$" { 
                  send_user "\n\nWaiting 30secs before next migration\n\n";
                  sleep 30; 
               }
             }
         }                 
         -re "Status: Failure\n" { send_user "\n\nExiting\n"; exit 1 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, you are right, should have edited the duplicacy before copy pasting the stuff but I'm kind on a hurry with this tests.. Anyways, I found what my problem was check my own answer.